# React Native error when using dynamic styling in combination with useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

The error I receive is:
[Invariant Violation: [369,"RCTImageView",31,{"source":[{"__packager_asset":true,"width":52,"height":80,"uri":"...assets/assets/glass.png?platform=ios&hash=b11854c2a0e54026f26338d7c7cbf7fc?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false","scale":1}],"width":"<>","height":"<>","overflow":"hidden","marginTop":4,"marginHorizontal":"<>","resizeMode":"contain"}] **is not usable as a native method argument**. It appears that the width, height and marginHorizontal are not available on render - I calculate these values based on screen size and the error disappears when I remove the dynamic styling. This error only happens when I use useEffect. I make the dynamic styling based on the width of a container:

```
 <View
   style={styles.container}
   onLayout={(event) => {
      setContainerWidth(event.nativeEvent.layout.width);
   }}
 >
   {glasses.map(() => glassContainer())}
 </View>
```

This is the component which uses the dynamic styling.

```
const ratio = 78 / 50;
const width = containerWidth / 12;

const glassContainer = () => (
    <View style={styles.singleGlassContainer}>
      <Image
        source={require("../../assets/glass.png")}
        style={[
          styles.glass,
          {
            width: width,
            height: width * ratio,
            marginHorizontal: containerWidth / 72,
          },
        ]}
        resizeMode="contain"
      />
    </View>
  );
```

Then finally I use useEffect like below

```
useEffect(() => {
    renderGlasses();
  }, [hydrationTarget]);
```

The renderGlasses function:

```
  const renderGlasses = () => {
    //Calculates amounth of glasses to reach target
    const targetGlasses = Math.ceil(hydrationTarget / glassVolume);
    for (let i = 0; i < targetGlasses; i++) {
      setGlasses((prevArray) => [...prevArray, i]);
    }
  };
```

I think what goes wrong is useEffect fires before the dynamic styling is calculated, but I might be wrong here. Anyone knows what is causing the error, and how to fix it? If any additional code is needed please let me know.

Comment: how do you get the width of the container? tried using useWindowDimensions?

Comment: @ErikDreifaldt I used  onLayout={(event) => {
      setContainerWidth(event.nativeEvent.layout.width);
   }}

Comment: my guess is that hydrationTarget is a const with useState? if so to have hydrationTarget as a dependency seems redundant because it would re-render anyways on hydrationTarget change. does the style styles.glass have any initial values for width and height?

Comment: hydrationTarget for now is still a let, and no - I'm haven't given any initial values, I will try to do so **edit:** giving initial values in the stylesheet object doesn't help